# Error in query (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, inner-join, alias

I'd like to use INNER JOIN on 2 tables, but when I try either of the below statements, I get

> Error in query (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t2.col)
FROM tab2 as t2
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col)
  FROM tab1 as t1
  WHERE t1.id>678 AND t1.id<5248
) ON t2.col=t1.col
WHERE t2.id>10 AND t2.id<3770

SELECT DISTINCT(col)
FROM tab2 as t2
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT(col)
  FROM tab1 as t1
  WHERE t1.id>678 AND t1.id<5248
) ON t2.col=t1.col
WHERE t2.id>10 AND t2.id<3770
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Required an alias of this `(SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col) FROM tab1 as t1 WHERE t1.id>678 AND t1.id<5248) `

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nee to add an alias to your join table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t2.col) FROM tab2 as t2 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col) FROM tab1 as t1 WHERE t1.id>678 AND t1.id<5248) as t3 ON t2.col=t3.col WHERE t2.id>10 AND t2.id<3770
```

Comment: Thanks! And it seems the inner one doesn't need the extra alias inside, since it's already aliased SELECT DISTINCT(t2.col) FROM tab2 as t2 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(col) FROM tab1 WHERE id>678 AND id<5248) as t1 ON t2.col=t1.col WHERE t2.id>10 AND t2.id<3770

Comment: Yep, DISTINCT still ain't a function.

Comment: ...and `ain't` isn't a word :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an alias for the join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t2.col) 
FROM tab2 as t2 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col) 
   FROM tab1 as t1 
   WHERE t1.id>678 AND t1.id<5248
) as myJoinName ON t2.col=myJoinName.col 
WHERE t2.id>10 AND t2.id<3770
```

Repeat for the second query. You also need to change the way you join to use this alias as t1 will be out of scope of the join condition.

Answer (score 0):

> Error in query (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias

This error is self-explanatory and is being caused by your subqueries not having an alias assigned to them.  In fact, every derived table needs an alias even if you don't use it.  Try the following queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.col
FROM tab2 as t2
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t.col
    FROM tab1 t
    WHERE t.id > 678 AND t.id < 5248
) t1
    ON t2.col = t1.col
WHERE t2.id > 10 AND t2.id < 3770

SELECT DISTINCT col 
FROM tab2 as t2
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT col 
    FROM tab1 as t
    WHERE t.id > 678 AND t.id < 5248
) t1
    ON t2.col = t1.col
WHERE t2.id > 10 AND t2.id < 3770
```